# Python Pandas resample doesn't resample

Tags: python, pandas

I have a timeseries in Panda, with frequent entries (+- every ten seconds). I try to resample to hourly entries, with the average value, but it doesn't have an effect.

What am I missing please?

Source:

```
import pandas as pd
tempfile = pd.read_csv("test.txt",";",squeeze=True)

tempfile["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(tempfile["datetime"])
tempfile = tempfile.set_index('datetime')
tempfile.resample("1h").mean()
print(tempfile)
```

Output:

```
                                temp
datetime
2021-02-10 23:39:55+00:00  17.620001
2021-02-10 23:40:26+00:00  17.500000
2021-02-10 23:40:49+00:00  17.500000
2021-02-10 23:40:52+00:00  17.500000
2021-02-10 23:41:33+00:00  17.500000
```

Comment: "resample" returns a resampled object. I assume you have to set the tempfile to the resampled data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `assign` the resampling back to `tempfile`:

```
tempfile=tempfile.resample("1h").mean()
```

Comment: Which is stated in my comment below the question